# How do I direct output to a file when there are UTF-8 characters?

Tags: python, linux, utf-8, ascii

I have a python script that grabs a bunch of recent tweets from the twitter API and dumps them to screen. It works well, but when I try to direct the output to a file something strange happens and a print statement causes an exception:

```
> ./tweets.py > tweets.txt
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 61: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I understand that the problem is with a UTF-8 character in one of the tweets that doesn't translate well to ASCII, but what is a simple way to dump the output to a file? Do I fix this in the python script or is there a way to coerce it at the commandline?

BTW, the script was written in Python2.

Comment: You should fix it in python script. encode the string with utf-8 encoding. eg: `print tweet.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: You will need to fix the Python script. The error is occurring in there, before anything is written to stdout (the message you are seeing is on stderr). Also, which version of Python? 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Did you try wrap output strings with the unicode? Like `u"text"` or `unicode("text")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without modifying the script, you can just set the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` and Python will assume that encoding when redirecting to a file.

References:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING
https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING

Answer (score 0):

You may need encode the unicode object with `.encode('utf-8')`

<s>In your python file append this to first line</s>

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If your script file is working standalone, append it to second line

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Here is the document: [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: This does not affect the encoding used in I/O *at all*. It's a good answer, but to a different question.